# Jenkins failing to load in linux Centos

Tags: linux, centos, jenkins, continuous-integration

Configured Jenkins, tried to change the port to: `5555` as `8080` is used by tomcat apache.

Edited: `vim /etc/sysconfig/jenkins` and updated `JENKINS_LISTEN_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0"` AND `JENKINS_ARGS="0.0.0.0"`

Restarted the jenkins Server: `sudo service jenkins restart`

**Error:**

> This site can’t be reached ipaddress took too long to respond. Try:
>
> Checking the connection Checking the proxy and the firewall
>   ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

`ps aux | grep jenkins`

```
jenkins   6799 33.4 15.7 3078760 296780 ?      Ssl  09:15   0:12 /etc/alternatives/java -Dcom.sun.akuma.Daemon=daemonized -Djava.awt.headless=true -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --daemon --httpPort=5555 --httpListenAddress=0.0.0.0 --debug=5 --handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20 0.0.0.0
root      6909  0.0  0.0 112680   740 pts/0    S<+  09:15   0:00 grep --color=auto jenkins
```

**Port 5555 looks fine with below query:**

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN

java       6799     jenkins  165u  IPv6 9250567      0t0  TCP *:5555 (LISTEN)
```

**Port 8080 is running for tomcat:**

```
java       6269        root   50u  IPv6   48458      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
```

**Anything missing in the configuration here?**

Comment: what about 8080 port status?

Comment: updated my question for 8080 as well

Comment: check the port status from outside of server, check if those are reachable and responding within time.

Comment: How to ping and test specific port?

Comment: The first thing to look at is your firewall.

Comment: Yup, the firewall was not configured for the port @MichaelHampton. Added there, thanks

Comment: Strange is, i was able to setup jenkins with default plugins and created username and password. Also able to login, but there is blank screen, dont know why ? :( @MichaelHampton

Comment: I am so stupid, i should do a restart of jenkins after configuration, It worked :)